# React: using custom hook inside regular function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use my custom hook inside a regular function as follows, but React won't let me do that. I wonder if my useUrl custom hook is not valid or there is something wrong with calling the hook.

```
const handleAddFormation = async () => {
    console.log('add formation')

    await useUrl('POST', 'http://localhost:1337/formations', newFormationList)

    setNewFormationList([])
    setModalOpen(false)
}
```

My custom hook:

```
export default function useUrl(method, url, args) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        axios({
            method,
            url,
            data: args
        })
        .then((res) => {
            setData(res.data)
            setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            setLoading(false)
        })
    }, [])

    if (!loading) return data
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
React Hook "useUrl" is called in function "handleAddFormation" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter
```

Comment: As the error message states, you can use custom hooks only in 2 cases , custom hooks inside another custom hook or inside the functional component . Your `handleAddFormation` is neither of those .

Comment: From what is understand you are trying to mimic something like this https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations . You need to make your custom hook to return a function which will run at the later point of time when you are doing create/update/delete operations .

Comment: @Shyam Yes, but how to point to a specific function within the custom hook file? For example I'd like to have one function for create and another one for delete.

Answer (score 5):

From react [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html),

Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:

✅ Call Hooks from React function components.

✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks

Also, you don't need use `await` for custom hook

Comment: What should my code be in order to make this work?

Comment: move useUrl from your handler, and use value that was returned in your handler

Comment: Makes sense, but I'd like to only make a post request in my handler, not everytime the components mounts.

Comment: in this case you should create a custom hook, which will return useCallback instead of value, and invoke it in your handler

`const getResource = useResourceCallback()

const handleAddFormation = async () => {
  const data = await getResource()
}`